# normalizing rows into unique rows by moving some values into columns

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that currently looks like this:

```
 index  serial          email     firstname     lastname     country     job    course     completed
     0    0005    one@two.com         David        Smith          US   Sales   course1            Y
     1    0076  three@two.com          John       Bloggs          GB    Exec   course2            Y
     2    0005    one@two.com         David        Smith          US   Sales   course2            Y
     3    0005    one@two.com         David        Smith          US   Sales   course3            Y
     4     NaN    foo@bar.com           Foo          Bar          IN     ext   course2            Y
     5     NaN    bar@foo.com           Bar          Far          NZ     ext   course2            Y
   ...     ...            ...           ...         ...          ...          ...           ...
```

I would like to normalize this dataframe so that a person only appears once (on one row). In other words I would like to transform it into something like this:

```
 index   serial           email     firstname     lastname     country     job    course1    course2    course3
     0     0005     one@two.com         David        Smith          US   Sales        Yes        Yes        Yes
     1     0076   three@two.com          John       Bloggs          GB    Exec        NaN        Yes        NaN
     2      NaN     foo@bar.com           Foo          Bar          IN     ext        NaN        Yes        NaN
     3      NaN     bar@foo.com           Bar          Far          NZ     ext        NaN        Yes        NaN
   ...      ...             ...           ...          ...         ...           ...        ...        ...
```

Please note that the unique identifiers is the serial for people in the company (job == Sales or Exec) and for external people (job == ext) it is their email.

Comment: Are there ever only 3 courses? If not then you maybe should use 2 (or even 3 tables) one for the employees and one for the courses (and maybe as a third table a relationship table which connects employees with courses; but that can be included directly into the course table)

Comment: No, there is a dynamic number of courses. I have the courses that are in the list in an array `selectedCourses`. I'm not looking to make a relationship table, simply an excel export so that you can see which courses an employee has completed, which can be filtered by the various columns.

Comment: Oh... Now I got it... Sadly I am not able to help there :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this,

```
dumm= (pd.get_dummies(df['course'])).astype(str).replace({'0':np.NaN,'1':'Yes'})
del df['course']
df=pd.concat([df,dumm],axis=1)
df=df.groupby('email').apply(lambda x:x.fillna(method='bfill'))
df=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['email'],keep='first')
```

Output:

```
   index  serial          email firstname lastname country    job completed  \
0      0     5.0    one@two.com     David    Smith      US  Sales         Y   
1      1    76.0  three@two.com      John   Bloggs      GB   Exec         Y   
4      4     NaN    foo@bar.com       Foo      Bar      IN    ext         Y   
5      5     NaN    bar@foo.com       Bar      Far      NZ    ext         Y   

  course1 course2 course3  
0     Yes     Yes     Yes  
1     NaN     Yes     NaN  
4     NaN     Yes     NaN  
5     NaN     Yes     NaN
```